# Form submitting with jquery error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

there is a registration form,  I check if the username is available or not.
If available then appears a text next to the username field into a paragraph ("Available!"), if not then ("Not available!").
I don't want to be submitted if the username is not available.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#usernameFeedback').load('check.php').show();

    $('#usernameID').keyup(function(){

        $.post('check.php',{username:registration.username.value},
        function(result){
            $('#usernameFeedback').html(result).show();
            var feedVar = $('#usernameFeedback').text();

        });
    });
});
</script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#regForm").submit(function(){
     alert("HELLO"); // works fine
     if ( $('#usernameFeedback').text() == "Not available!" )
        return;
   event.preventDefault();
   });
});

</script>
```

With this code doesn't work properly (I am new to jquery), doesn't stay in the current page if the username is not available..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the event to the function.

```
$("#regForm").submit(function(){
```

should be

```
$("#regForm").submit(function(event){
```

And use the `return false` in the same line as the `if`, since you are not using `{}`

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#regForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("HELLO"); // works fine
        if ($('#usernameFeedback').text() == "Not available!") {return false;}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

an `if()` statement without curly brackets will only listen the first and only statement below it. If you include the curly brackets, you can have multiple statements, like below:

```
   if ( $('#usernameFeedback').text() == "Not available!" ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
```

Furthermore, the `event.preventDefault()` won't ever execute with your current code, as the function is left before it's even able to execute, thus I've swapped those around, it's prevented by Default, *then* returned.

And Sergio quickly and rightly mentions, add `event` to function, to even allow you to `event.preventdefault()` in the first place!

Comment: On a side note, you should also avoid evaluating the `.text()` content of `#usernameFeedback` because it can be modified by the user. Instead, try storing the server response in a variable, e.g. `var usernameAvailability` and assign it a value of true or false based on the server response.

Prior to form submission, you can evaluate this variable and determine if the submission should proceed or not.